# WPF: Custom window, standard min/max/close buttons

Tags: wpf, windows, custom-controls, window-chrome

I would like to create a custom WPF window (WindowStyle = None, AllowsTransparency = True). However, I would like the min/max/close buttons to look identical to those on standard windows. Is this possible?

Comment: You mean standard according to the current system theme? (Aero, classic etc.)

Comment: exactly. i'd like them to be drawn exactly like they would be using the current system theme.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to have a look at GlassWindow in FluidKit at CodePlex
http://fluidkit.codeplex.com/

The source code has a custom Window Style looking like this. It's pretty easy to modify to however you want it to look. I've used it once and it works good

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to "draw" them yourself, since you're using `WindowStyle=None`.  When choosing this option, you'll need to render your own Chrome as desired.